# Invalid value for property <position> with two level iframe context

Tags: properties

I'm having problem setting marker position and map center, with "Invalid value for property " error or "invalid value for property " error such as:

> Error: Invalid value for property : (13.7323691218542,
>   100.64347976627096) Source File:
>       http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/5/main.js Line: 26

This is based on tests on Firefox and Chrome

My top HTML contains:
 Javascript function "`move_it()`"
 An iframe (id: "mapIframe") sourced by a cgi (nwfMap.cgi)

And the "mapIframe" iframe cgi contains:
 A var mapNwf for a map
 A var markerMe for a marker
 An iframe (id: "myInfoIframe") sourced by a cgi (nwfSetInfo.cgi)

And the "myInfoIframe" iframe cgi contains:
 A call to the function "`move_it()`" defined in top HTML
 This call is intended to move the marker (markerMe) to a specific location
 and also to set the map (mapNwf) center to the same specific location

The invocation of the "`move_it`" was executed OK until when it tried to do:
`mrk.setPosition(pos);` or

```
mp.setCenter(pos);
```

It's here I've encountered the "Invalid value for property ..." errors.
The immediately preceding execution were of:

```
alert('mp = [' + mp.getCenter() + ']'); and
alert('mrk = [' + mrk.getPosition() + ']');
```

were OK with correct location (lat/lng) value displayed (map center and marker position)

So the question is, how come `getCenter` and `getPosition` worked for same map and marker variables, but the `setCenter` and `setPosition` had failed?

If `getCenter` and `getPosition` came back with correct data, it indicates that there's no variable context issues, right?

But then how come I can only "read" but not "set" the values via these variables?

Would it be related to the appearance of the google line:

in the top HTML, and in its iframe, and in the iframe's iframe?
Repetition and the nested level causing some google map context issue leading to my problem?

Much thanks in advance for any advice! Followings are relevant code portions for your examination and investigation:

**Relevant portions of the top HTML**

```
<html>
........
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function move_it(slat, slng) {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById('mapIframe');
    var mp = ifrm.contentWindow.mapNwf;
    var mrk = ifrm.contentWindow.markerMe;
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(slat,slng);
    alert('mp = [' + mp.getCenter() + ']');
    alert('mrk = [' + mrk.getPosition() + ']');
    alert('pos = [' + pos + ']');
    mrk.setPosition(pos);
    mp.setCenter(pos);
}
</script>
.........
<div id="nwfMap">
<iframe width=100% height=520 frameBorder=0 src="nwfMap.cgi" name="mapIframe"    id="mapIframe" scrolling=no></iframe>
</div>
........
</html>
```

**Relevant portions of the "mapIframe" iframe (produced by nwfMap.cgi)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mapNwf = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});
var latLngPre = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
var markerMe = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLngPre,
    title: 'Me Here',
    map: mapNwf,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });
.........
</script>
.........
<div id="myInfoForm" style="display: none;">
<iframe border=1 width=100% height=200 align=center marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 seamless=seamless frameBorder=0 src="nwfSetInfo.cgi" name="myInfoIframe" id="myInfoIframe" scrolling=no></iframe>
</div>
.........
```

**Relevant portions of the "myInfoIframe" iframe (produced by nwfSetInfo.cgi)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   parent.parent.move_it(13.7323691218542, 100.643479766271);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed now, by moving the "move_it()" function definition down from the top level HTML to the mid-level iframe "mapIframe" and by changing the "move_it()" invocation in the "myInfoIframe" iframe from

```
parent.parent.move_it(13.7323691218542, 100.643479766271);
```

to

```
parent.move_it(13.7323691218542, 100.643479766271);
```

Don't know why, but obviously by the reducing of invocation context level something got corrected on the original "can read but not write on map variable" problem. If any one has a good explanation, would like to hear about it. Thanks.